# Embed external content without iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, embed

All,
  I have a requirement where I need to embed external content, owned by us, into a new application without an iframe.

This requirement gets complex quickly.  Imagine the following mock code as the content I need to embed.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/someScript1.js"></script> <!-- drag and drop -->
<script src="js/someScript2.js"></script> <!-- ajax communication -->
<script src="js/someScript3.js"></script> <!-- ux stuff -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="appContainer">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="toolbar">
          Toolbar that interacts with both draggablePicklist and content
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="dragablePicklist">
          Unordered list of elements that can be dragged into content
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="content">
          Content area where things are built based on items dragged in from dragablePicklist
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The root application is a JavaEE app and ends up being built out for the client in javascript.  The problem is this is a large product, hundreds of thousands of lines of javascript for the client application.  Of which there is next to no documentation that is relevant.

My requirement, using the above mock HTML as an example, is to be able to pick and choose which selectors I want in my app, while retaining context and functionality.

Example:

I can drag content from draggablePicklist into content, then the javascript builds out a view.

I'd like to be able to embed draggablePicklist in my current page as well as content, in their own containers but retain my drag and drop.

Now I have two options.  Forgetting selecting specific items, I just tried loading the entire application.

Option 1

```
<script>$("#testLoad").load("http://www.domain.com/myapp");</script>
<div id="testLoad"></div>
```

But the canvas disappears immediately after I see it loaded.

Option 2

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "http://www.domain.com/myapp", function() {
})
  .done(function(d) {
    console.log( "second success" );
    $('#test').html(d);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
  });

jqxhr.always(function(d) {
  console.log( "second finished" );
});
```

This appears like it would probably work but I will need to include the javascript "myapp" depends on in this page.  I'll also need to find and replace all hrefs with absolute url's.

As you can see there are a lot of moving parts.  What would be the best way to embed specific DIV's from another page into mine, without and iframe WHILE maintaining these div's functionality.

Comment: Have you tried the `object` element? ... Read more here about embedding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I tried object.  This is also disappearing on me after loading

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am able to embed the entire application.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("html").html('<object data="http://www.domain.com/myapp">');
});
```

Now I need to figure out how I can select specific parts of this application using the above method.  So this is 50% solved.

Comment: were you able to figure out how to select a dom object?